# Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?' Alamofire ObjectMapper

Tags: swift, swift2, alamofire

Cannot call value of non-function type 'NSHTTPURLResponse?'[image]

Can someone please help me here?

Here is the code

```
   public func responseObject<T: Mappable>(queue: dispatch_queue_t?, keyPath: String?, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, T?, AnyObject?, ErrorType?) -> Void) -> Self {

    return response(queue: queue, responseSerializer: Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)) { request, response, result in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            let parsedObject = Mapper<T>().map(keyPath != nil ? result.value?[keyPath!] : result.value)

            dispatch_async(queue ?? dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                completionHandler(self.request!, self.response, parsedObject, result.value ?? result.data, result.error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My bad, I did not notice the return type of Alamofire 2.0,

This is fixed, updated code is here

```
public func responseObject<T: Mappable>(queue: dispatch_queue_t?, keyPath: String?, completionHandler: (NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, T?, AnyObject?, ErrorType?) -> Void) -> Self {

let serializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: NSJSONReadingOptions.AllowFragments)

return response(queue: queue, responseSerializer: serializer) { (Response) -> Void in

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            let parsedObject = Mapper<T>().map(keyPath != nil ? Response.result.value?[keyPath!] : Response.result.value)



            dispatch_async(queue ?? dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                completionHandler(self.request!, self.response, parsedObject, Response.result.value ?? Response.result.value, Response.result.error)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I tried using the Alamofire 2.0 response serializer, this also gives the same error

Comment: Please write down your code, do not post an screenshoot.

Comment: I have added the code. Any idea?

Comment: I have to use `responseJSON` or `responseData` instead

Answer (score 3):

Had this error myself and took a while to figure out why it was occurring. It looks like if the parameters to the `response()` method call don't match to any method declarations then swift assumes your code is referring to the `response` property, a `NSHTTPURLResponse`. Because there the property that "shadows" the method's name, swift can't help you out with errors that indicate which parameter is a problem, it just punts on matching to any method.

In my case, `completionHandler` was mismatched because of *its* parameters. Note, its the sample code I saw `.response { response in ... }` that's problematic. There's no `response` method taking a "response in" closure like there is for the `responseString`, `responseJSON`, etc. methods.

That said, [Abh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/864717/abh), I can't tell from looking what the exact issue is with your code.

Comment: I fixed the arguments to `completionHandler` in my use of the `response(queue queue: dispatch_queue_t? = nil, completionHandler: ...) -> Self` method, changing `.response { response in ... }` as copied from sample code to `.response { _, _, _, error in ... }`

Comment: Thanks for your response but it was not possible for me to post my code here, so I asked a new question. It looks like you can answer it, please do help and I'll gladly accept your answer if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838463/alamofire-error-after-updating-to-latest-version

Comment: Not the same `response()` method as I was using, so my solution doesn't quite help you. I'll post an answer to your new Q if I can think of anything general to suggest. But essentially its the same core problem: because Alamofire defines a `response` property its preventing swift from showing a helpful error for the `response` method.

Comment: I stumbled upon the same error message/situation. 

The reason for it turned out to be of the same kind: Mismatch of the method signature. But in my case I used a `try` without a `catch` inside the function and I guess that changes the methods signature (adding a `throws`) and therefore the mismatch. 

Adding a `catch` to the `try` solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark your completionHandler as @escaping.