# "Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?'" (Alamofire 4.0) [Swift 3.0]

Tags: swift, alamofire, swift3

I'm receiving this error:

> "Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?'"

on the section:

```
.response { (request, response, data, error)
```

and I was wondering if anyone can help me with this.

```
Alamofire.download(urlToCall, method: .get) { temporaryURL, response in
    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: finalPath!.path!) {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: finalPath!.path!)
        } catch {
            // Error - handle if required
        }
    }
    return finalPath!

    }
    .response { (request, response, data, error) in

        if error != nil {

        }
        var myDict: NSDictionary?
        let path = finalPath!
        myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOf: path)

        if let dict = myDict {
            success(dict)
        }

        if finalPath != nil {
            //doSomethingWithTheFile(finalPath!, fileName: fileName!)
        }
}
```

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32932748/3303915

Comment: Nope. Similar issue but not the same. Different versions of swift and alamofire.

Comment: Are you targeting iOS 8? I don't know the reason but Alamofire for Swift 3 has to be at least iOS 9. Regards

Comment: @JordanClark - Perhaps different versions, but the issue is the same. Your parameters to the closure are incorrect.

Comment: Incidentally, is your server really sending back a plist for `NSDictionary`? That's a little unusual. Usually it's JSON or something like that.

Comment: I have to use responseJSON or responseData instead

Answer (score 0):

In Alamofire 4, the `.response` method takes a closure with a single parameter, the `DefaultDownloadResponse`.

By the way, if you're going to use your own path for the download, I'm confused by your `return finalPath!` because Alamofire 4 expects you to return a tuple consisting of the file URL and the options, of which one of the options is `.removePreviousFile`, which saves you from manually removing it yourself.

For example:

```
Alamofire.download(urlToCall, method: .get) { temporaryURL, response in
    let finalURL: URL = ...

    return (destinationURL: finalURL, options: .removePreviousFile)
}.response { response in
    if let error = response.error {
        success(nil)
        return
    }

    if let fileURL = response.destinationURL, let dictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOf: fileURL) {
        success(dictionary)
    } else {
        success(nil)
    }
}
```