# Cannot call value of non-function type HTTPURLResponse?

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I am working with Alamofire 4, in Swift 3.

I am getting an error saying

> Cannot  call value of non-function type HTTPURLResponse?

I'm trying to download an image and store it in cache, here is my code below, can anyone help?

```
            request = Alamofire.request(post.imageUrl!).validate(contentType: ["image/*"]).response(completionHandler: { request,data, err  in


                if err == nil {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)!
                    self.showcaseImage.image = image
            FeedVC.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: self.post.imageUrl!)

                }
            })
```

i found that i had to change the top part to just .response. but when i do that I cannot go to if err == nil bloc and set image as data. is there away to fix this. code below.

```
request = Alamofire.request( post.imageUrl!).validate(contentType: ["application/json"]).response { response in
                debugPrint(response)

                if error == nil {
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)!
```

all the best
Tony

Comment: Have you checked [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39518885/6541007)?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the documentation and was able to solve this. By changing the code to.

```
  request = Alamofire.request(post.imageUrl!).validate(contentType: ["image/*"])
                .response { response in

                print(response.error)

                if response.error == nil {
                    let image = UIImage(data: response.data!)!
```

I wrote response.error and then response.data, this was the same as calling `request, response, data, error` that solved my problem of moving on with the error and data.